# Accessing a non-global variable in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, gtk

I'm trying to change the state of a Gtk status icon from a thread as specified in MailThread.run() below, but I don't know how to reach the status icon object from the method in order to change set_visible to either True or False.

Basically I would like to know what to write in place of "# set status icon visible off/on".

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gtk, sys, pynotify, imaplib, time, threading
from email import parser

class Mail:

    def check_mail(self):
        obj = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com','993')
        acc = 'email'
        pwrd = 'pass'
        obj.login(acc, pwrd)
        obj.select()
        num = str(len(obj.search(None,'UnSeen')[1][0].split()))
        return acc, num

class MailThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        gtk.gdk.threads_init()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print "hello"
            mail = Mail()
            num = mail.check_mail()[1]
            if num < 1:
                # set status icon visible off
            else:
                # set status icon visible on
            time.sleep(60)

class StatusIcon:

    # activate callback
    def activate( self, widget, data=None):
        mail = Mail()
        acc, num = mail.check_mail()
        pynotify.init("myapp")
        n = pynotify.Notification(acc, "You have " + num + " unread e-mails.", "emblem-mail")
        n.show()

   # Show_Hide callback
    def  show_hide(self, widget,response_id, data= None):
        if response_id == gtk.RESPONSE_YES:
            widget.hide()
        else:
            widget.hide()

    # destroyer callback
    def  destroyer(self, widget,response_id, data= None):
        if response_id == gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
            gtk.main_quit()
        else:
            widget.hide()

    # popup callback
    def popup(self, button, widget, data=None):
        dialog = gtk.MessageDialog(
        parent         = None,
        flags          = gtk.DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,
        type           = gtk.MESSAGE_INFO,
        buttons        = gtk.BUTTONS_OK_CANCEL,
        message_format = "Do you want to close e-mail notifications?")
        dialog.set_title('Exit')
        dialog.connect('response', self.destroyer)
        dialog.show()

    def __init__(self):
        # create a new Status Icon
        self.staticon = gtk.StatusIcon()
        self.staticon.set_from_icon_name("emblem-mail")
        self.staticon.connect("activate", self.activate)
        self.staticon.connect("popup_menu", self.popup)
        self.staticon.set_visible(True)
        # starting thread
        thread = MailThread()
        thread.setDaemon(True)
        thread.start()
        # invoking the main()
        gtk.main()        

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # status icon
    statusicon = StatusIcon()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accept the status icon in the thread's `__init__()`:

```
class MailThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, status_icon = None):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        gtk.gdk.threads_init()
        self.status_icon = status_icon
```

And then you can use it in `run()`.

Additionally, you need to do all the GUI work from the main thread. The main thread has a queue maintained by GTK you can use to tell it to go do some GUI work. This is how it works:

```
def run(self):
    # <...>
    if num < 1:
        gobject.idle_add(self.set_status_icon, False)
    else:
        gobject.idle_add(self.set_status_icon, True)
    # <...>

def set_status_icon(self, state = False):
    # code that changes icon state goes here
    pass
```

`idle_add` basically means "add that to the queue and do it when you have some free time".

Comment: Thank you, cha0site. Found the check mark.

It fixed the problem, but I'm getting some strange "BadIDChoice" error when changing the icon from not visible to visible. The other way works fine.

Comment: @Max: Well, this is because this is not really the way to write multithreaded code in GTK. Basically the idea is that you need to do all the GUI work from the main thread - I'll edit my answer to show you how to do this.

Comment: Marvelous! I think I have some reading to do, but it works as intended now. :)